# QDialog exec returning Rejected always

Tags: exec, qdialog

I have a QDialog box which accepts password and has a Ok button. When closing the Dialog box on "X", a function should be called. But that function is being called even if clicked on Ok button. Qdialog exec function is always returning Rejected. 
Code:

```
if (password->exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
  QString passwordText = passwordEntry->text();
   }
  else 
  {
  sshDialogBoxClosed();
  }
  delete password;
```

In any case sshDialogBoxClosed() function is being called.
Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you please add the connect for your accept and reject button?

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect the "**Ok**" button with the "*accept*" slot and the "**Cancel**" button with the "*reject*" slot.

```
QDialog::connect(AcceptButton,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(accept()));
QDialog::connect(RejectButton,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(reject()));
```